# Convolution between normal distribution and the maximum over $m$ Gaussian draws

Tags: pr.probability, integration, gaussian, closed-form-expressions, convolution

$\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}$
Let's consider the Gaussian distribution $P_X(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} e^{- \frac{x^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$. Now consider the random variable $W \equiv \max \{ X_1, \dots , X_m \}$, where $X_i \sim P_X(x)$. So $w$ indicates the maximum over $m$ i.i.d. Gaussian draws; we call $P_W(w)$ the corresponding distribution. $P_W(w)$ can be easily calculated from the formula $P_Y(y)=mP_X(y)F_X(y)^{m-1}$, where $F_X(y)$ is the c.d.f. of $P_X(x)$. We get:

$$P_Y(y)= m \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} e^{- \frac{y^2}{2 \sigma^2}} \left(\frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \erf \left( \frac{y}{\sqrt{2} \sigma}\right) \right) \right)^{m -1}$$

I'm interested in the convolution between $P_X(x)$ and $P_W(w)$, i.e.:

$$I(\Delta) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P_X(x') P_W(x'+ \Delta) \, dx'$$

Is it possible to get an analytical closed form or even an approximated solution for $I(\Delta)$?

Comment: It seems odd that you initially call the random variable $w=\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}$ but then write $P_W(w),$ as if (capital) $W$ is the random variable and (lower-case) $w$ is the argument to its density function.

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Comment: I only read the headline, but won't the convolution with the max give the distribution of X + Max, and isn't that the distribution of max(X+X_1, ..., X + X_n) ?

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely unlikely that a closed-form expression for this exists in general.

Mathematica cannot find such an expression even when $\sigma=1$, $m=3$, and $\Delta=0$:

[image]